# error: local class incompatible: stream classdec serialversionUID= ...., local class serialversionUID=

Tags: java, serialization, file-io

I have a serializable java class and when I add either of the following methods. I get this error

" local class incompatible: stream classdec serialversionUID= ...., local class serialversionUID=..."

added methods:

```
public HashMap<Long, BookIndex> getBookIndexMap() {
    return bookIndexMap;
}

public String getDataFileName() {
    return dataFileName;
}
```

what is causing this and how can I correct it?

Comment: Add `static long serialVersionUID = ..;` to the class, with the value as shown for the stream classdesc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111104124500/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/05/04/upgrading-java-classes-backward-compatible-serialization/) may be helpful, by changing the class's method signatures, previous serialized forms are incompatible unless the classes have the same serialVersionUID.

Comment: The Object Serialization Specification would be a lot more helpful, as it is a normative specification, not just some arbitrary third-party Internet junk.

Answer (score -1):

Even Though the serialVersionUID is same, some changes are incompatible to sync with the previous serialized form.

[link is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640859/error-local-class-incompatible-stream-classdec-serialversionuid-local-c%22%3E%20Versioning%20of%20serialized%20forms)

Comment: Those incompatibilities do not cause this error. Answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by doing the following:

Working in Eclipse Neon.

#### On Tomcat Server

- Clean Tomcat Work Directory...
- Clean... (to do something, just in case)

then

#### Project

- 'Clean...' select your project and click 'Ok'

Comment: That wouldn't take care of existing serializations, such as to files or databases. This is not the correct solution.