# java.io.InvalidClassException - Tomcat fails to start

Tags: java, tomcat

When I try to run the project or start Tomcat I keep getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.turktrust.iab.ebs.backingbeans.MetalCikisIslemleriBean; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5362381638722129852, local class serialVersionUID = -3788780881701361526
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:562)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1509)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:998)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:446)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4631)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

This problem occurred after I got an update from SVN. It looks like there is some incompatibility in MetalCikisIslemleriBean class.I searched for this exception and as a solution I added

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5362381638722129852L;
```

to the MetalCikisIslemleriBean but still it does no good. Tomcat is not starting. Does anyone have any recommendation about this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I installed another Tomcat version but still no good. I deleted files under Tomcat's work & temp directory and project's build folder. This time Tomcat runs, cleaning & building of project is fine but it still doesn't run. What I realized is that in the backingbeans folder of the project there are 2 class files of MetalCikisIslemleriBean: MetalCikisIslemleriBean$1 and MetalCikisIslemleriBean..

EDIT & SOLUTION:
Tomcat was caching the war file of the project. When I deleted the war from Tomcat's cache (In Netbeans: Services Panel - Servers - Tomcat - Web Applications) the problem was resolved. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `com.turktrust.iab.ebs.backingbeans.MetalCikisIslemleriBean` has been changed by anyone else in SVN, so you are getting an `java.io.InvalidClassException`.

The problem is, that you have store data (your sessions?) with the *old* version of this class on any local storage and now you are trying to load it with the *new* version. Depending on the change of your class this could not be possible.

Easiest **solution** is to remove your session data from local storage (maybe working directory) - But be careful, as you are going to lose all information, stored in your user sessions.

**UPDATE**

Try to remove all files from the temp and work directory, when tomcat is down

Comment: Please check if your application uses any other folder to store the session data.

Comment: Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640859/error-local-class-incompatible-stream-classdec-serialversionuid-local-c

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Tomcat persisted a previous version of your compiled class when it was shut down some time. Later you deployed a recompiled updated version of your applicaton. When Tomcat wants to restore the persisted session it cannot do it because he notices from the `serialVersionUID` that the class changed. If there is no important data in that old persisted session I suggest simply deleting it by removing the `SESSIONS.ser` file. I think it might be in the `work` directory.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But there is no SESSIONS.ser under Tomcat directory, neither in any folder..

Comment: What version of Tomcat do you use? What about tldCache.ser?